# Carregar component dinamicamente com angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Preciso carregar componentes dinamicamente, estou usando o jsPanel para criar uma window e gostaria de passar qual o módulo que será criado dentro desta window.
É possível fazer isso, abaixo trecho do código, openWindow é chamado a partir de um botão, *meu-componente* é qualquer um dos componentes da minha aplicação que preciso carregar no conteúdo do painel que será aberto.

```
openWindow(event) {
  jsPanel.create({
    theme: 'gainsboro',
    headerTitle: 'my panel #1',
    position: 'center-top 0 58',
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content: '<meu-component></meu-component>',
  });}
```

Comment: tem algum motivo pra você ter que usar o jspanel especificamente? Tem outras bibliotecas de modals compatíveis com o angular.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Eduardo, pode ser qualquer outra biblioteca, porém eu não quero uma janela modal, gostaria de abrir várias janelas ao mesmo tempo, com componentes diferentes em cada janela. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Alguma evolução nesse problema @RonaldoAlberton?